# Special characters in HTTP request fields

Tags: http, webserver

This isn't really related to programming, but I'm using this in a program, so I thought it would be best to ask here. Essentially this is a question about handling anomalies in HTTP requests.

A standard request might look like:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Firefox
```

My question is, how should HTTP handle "special characters" in parts of the HTTP request that aren't usually tampered with. For instance, what if the method was "POST ME" instead of "GET" (i.e. inclusion of a space); would this be encoded to %20?

Another example, suppose I want one of my headers to be "Class:Test: example", with the extra ":" in the header name (the header value being "example"). Would this be encoded to %3A?

Note: this isn't about whether any web servers out there would accept such encoding; this is about how it should be done. My program is a fuzz tester, so it is supposed to be testing this sort of thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two question must be answered as "no" and "yes, BUT..."

The "percent encoding" you suggest is defined for content, values, not for the http language syntax. You mix protocol and payload.

You may want to take a look at the RFC that defines HTTP. It clearly defines a syntax. If you stick to that syntax you can create valid extensions (which is what you are trying to do). If you break that syntax you create invalid http requests. That would be a thing you can do inhouse, but most likely such requests won't work in the open internet, where for example proxies come into play. These have to understand your requests on y syntactical level.

For question 2 the answer is "yes, BUT", I wrote. So a few words to the BUT:

You can specify such headers and they are valid, if you encode the *second* ':' as you suggested. However you should understand what you are doing there: you are NOT introducing a hierarchy into header names. Instead you specify a headers content to contain a ':'. That is perfectly fine. It is up to your server component to understand, interpret and react as intended to that content.

Comment: Right, but my question wasn't about whether it would work on the open internet; just how it should be done. If I understand you correctly, there isn't any encoding mechanism defined for people who want to send "POST ME" as a HTTP method.

It wasn't the second ":" I was going to encode; that would mean the header value would be "Test: example", when I wanted the header *name* to be "Class:Test", with a value of "example".

Yes, I understand I'm not creating a hierarchy here...

Comment: I did understand your question. I just tried to explain how things work by referring to the internet. AFAIK "POST ME" is indeed an invalid request method name. So you can specify it, but it is undefined what happens. So where is the point in testing it? Except you are looking for things like buffer overflows and so on. But in that case thinking about "how it is done" does not make sense again.  A header name "Class:Test" is invalid. The same remark as above applies.

Comment: They didn't bother defining encoding mechanisms for this because it's simply unnecessary. They already have a way to have multi-word header names, use a hyphen as the separator. Why would you need ":" in a header name? And instead of "POST ME", you could use "POSTME" or "POST-ME".

Comment: "So where is the point in testing it?" -- This is what fuzz testing is all about, testing protocols with invalid values to see how clients / servers react. If both are invalid and there is no standard way of encoding such values, then I'll just leave it up to the user how to encode them. Thanks, that's all the info I needed. :)

Comment: @Barmar: It's not whether someone would ever need ":" in a header, it's whether such characters can be tested as part of an HTTP fuzz tester, which is supposed to use invalid characters to test the underlying protocol.

Comment: What do you mean "test the underlying protocol"? You don't test protocols, you test implementations. If you send an invalid HTTP request, you should get an error response.  So make up any encoding you want, and if you don't get an error then the server has a bug (or perhaps they consider it an extension).

Comment: Implementation is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP specification says that the method is a token, so it can't contain any delimiter characters. So "POST ME" would not be a valid method.

Similarly, header names are also tokens, so they can't contain ":". The colon is always taken to be the delimiter between the header name and its contents.

As arkascha says, you should read RFC 2616, which specifies the HTTP protocol.

Comment: I have read it. I was just wondering whether anything else had been written that covered such cases.

Answer (score 0):

For your method containing a space, this is not possible, since a request-line is defined as this:

```
    Request-Line   = Method SP Request-URI SP HTTP-Version CRLF
```

`Method` is defined as one of the HTTP/1.1 verbs or an extension-method, being a `token` (which cannot contain spaces). So the first space the server encounters marks the end of the method. Therefore, a method cannot contain spaces. You can percent-encode it, but the server won't know what to do with a verb like `GET%20ME`.

For your `Class:Test: example`, the http header is [defined](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-32) as:

```
message-header = field-name ":" [ field-value ]
field-name     = token
field-value    = *( field-content | LWS )
field-content  = <the OCTETs making up the field-value
                    and consisting of either *TEXT or combinations
                    of token, separators, and quoted-string>
```

And TEXT is defined as:

```
TEXT           = <any OCTET except CTLs,
                 but including LWS>
```

And CTL is defined as:

```
CTL            = <any US-ASCII control character
                 (octets 0 - 31) and DEL (127)>
```

So no, you don't have to escape further colons (58), the first one in a header-line is always accounted as being a separator, since a colon is not allowed in a `token`.

So in your example the field-name is `Class`, while the `field-value` is `Test: example`.

Comment: Right, but this isn't what I asked. To clarify, I wanted the header name to be "Class:Test" and the value to be "example", not the header name to be "Class" and the value to be "Test: example". This kind of behaviour apparently isn't defined in the HTTP spec; ":" in header names are simply not allowed.

Comment: @Rsaesha yes it is defined, as being not allowed. You *cannot* have a colon in an HTTP header name.